# How do i trim the extra space between the last character of text and the end of the rectangle bounding the text in a static control in MFC?

Tags: mfc

How do i trim the extra space between the last character of text and the end of the rectangle bounding the text in a static control. I have got the rectangle bound for the given string using the draw Text() function. but it is giving rectangle which has width greater than the size of text and i can see the extra space between the last character of string and the rectangle right point. I want to trim the gap please help.

Comment: what is the type of variable that holds the string?

Comment: i have created a static control on the dialog and added a variable of type cstring to that.

Answer (score 0):

To trim trailing space(s) from a `CString` variable, use the [CString::TrimRight() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fy06s064%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> It trims any trailing whitespace characters from the end of the
>   CStringT string. Whitespace characters can be line breaks, spaces, or
>   tabs

Example code:

```
strText = strText.TrimRight();
```

Comment: Hi, you didn't get my point. there are no whitespaces in the string. the rectangle bounded by string formed from drawtext() has given me extra width than that of length of string. so we are able to see that whitespace

Comment: Could you edit the question and add code that you use to calculate the rectangle and to draw the text?